# Clear or selectively remove Remote Desktop Connection history

Tags: windows, mstsc

Microsoft RDC on Windows (to open type **mstsc** in Start -> Run ) saves the history of previous computers you have connected to in the "Computer" dropdown.

[image]

How can I clear them, or selfectively delete entries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done in **Regedit**

Open Regedit (Windows Key + R >> and then type in *regedit* >> **Enter**

Navigate to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default**

Then you can delete the entries starting with **MRU** and followed by a number.

The above registry will only store the 10 most recent unique connections, so navigating to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Server** and deleting all the folders under **Server** will fully clear the history.

You may not be able to remove the last typed in location, it wont be in the list but it will be in the *Computer:* text field.

You could also use this FixtIt tool from Microsoft:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312169

Comment: But my dear, changes in history is always risky and cumbersome process. So, I want any tool through that I can do it easily.

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja I have edited my answer with a link to Microsoft website where you can download a tool to do it.  I don't know if it will work as I would just use regedit myself.